# Random revenge downvote without a reason

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I got recently a few downvotes done in a couple of seconds interval... Is it possible, that someone just didn't take my criticism and went through my answers and randomly downvoted some of them? What can do with such suspicion? Can a moderator see who is downvoting?

Comment: I wouldn't worry or read into it too much, these things happen. If I were to hazard a guess, the first because it's phrased very speculatively, the second because it didn't work for some short time (and it also looks like there were a few other answers covering the same territory).

Comment: If it were more than two in a suspiciously short period of time, you might have cause to flag down a moderator, but any blatant vote fraud is usually caught and reversed automatically.

Comment: Looking at answers I understand there is nothing I can do. Please don't get my question wrong - it is not about the fact being downvoted, but about the suspicion that these downvotes are random "revenge" for some maybe a bit more harsh comments.

Comment: get like 2/5ths of a up vote on another answer, get your rep back, and be don with it

Comment: I [must have misplaced my keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-down-voting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397), sorry about that.

Comment: Note that Moderators _cannot_ see who voted for whom.

Comment: @3524344 I've learned that from comments bellow. I originally thought that they can see individual votes... that would allow them to address my "problem".

Comment: @PavelHoral: they are cr..., non-constructive people who would not survive in another community. SO is a bit special in this regard. It gives a platform for people to criticize without objective (and hence constructive) comments, and in fact, on Meta it is even for free; no reputation lost! These people will go and downvote _everything_, including severe bugreports.

Comment: @PavelHoral sure just by posting here I have been downvoted more than 20 points even on posts favorited by almost 50 people. This prove the point. Some downvote occurs immediately not even 1 second after it's been posted. I hope someone will do like plentyoffish and take over Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's not a lot you can do.

People down-vote for all sorts of reasons, and the reputation cost of a down-vote is more than outweighed by the reputation gained from an up-vote. So as long as your answer is still scoring zero or more you're still gaining rep.

If you're sure that your answers are OK then just move on look for something else to answer.

Moderators can't see individual votes so if someone has down-voted one or two of your posts we're not going to be able to spot it. There is an automatic script that will reverse serial down-votes (and serial up-votes too) which runs nightly. We can see if this has been triggered. If you spot something that looks like serial down-voting that hasn't been picked up then flag one of the posts for us to investigate further.

Comment: Well the thing is that it makes me want to delete those answers. I kind of hate the fact they have negative vote count. And of course it makes me a bit angry.

Comment: Accepting this one. I understand that there is nothing I can do. But more importantly there is nothing a moderator can do as well as they don't see who downvoted.

Comment: @Pavel, *"it makes me want to delete those answers"* Don't, if you think they matter and are quite sure they're just retaliation downvotes. (My only negatively scored answer was anonymously downvoted after some Meta discussion, by someone who in their profile claims that people who downvote without commenting are cowards, and who has been trying/failed to game the system on multiple occasions... So, I don't care about *their* opinion. Even more: I feel that answer is right, as it solved the problem for me, and I'm sure it will help someone else one day.)

Comment: -1 to this answer. Reason: If you're sure that your answers are OK then just move on look for something else to answer. -> That is IMHO an impractical advice in a low-volume tag where 2-3 revenge downvotes can hurt the reputation of a good answer, thus the motivation of a valuable contributor, too.

Comment: Note that random revenge downvote can come from a community where the serial downvoter script will not help. There are several people, including me, whom the community downvotes no matter what is posted. I got 15 unexplained downvotes within three weeks on Stack Overflow without the moderators being to catch anything. Now tell me that it is normal. Another practical example is downvoting a valid bugreport that even an SE employee was surprised about. Yet another, I was writing almost the same as another answer, and I got -10, and the person taking my answer partially, I do not know, +15.

Comment: I think Your Common Sense was one of the leaders for getting unexplained revenge community downvotes in a huge amount on daily basis. No wonder he has got upset at times. I have never understood that either. Perhaps these people need a DownvoteOverflow subpage.

Comment: @FinalContest: Maybe th reason you're getting downvoted is because you keep saying you're getting downvoted for no reason.

Comment: Misusing votes, I agree, but I'm just saying it could be a reason, that's all. You don't have to tell me I shouldn't vote like that, 'cause I'm not.

Comment: @FinalContest: This is not the place for that discussion. If you have a problem with my answer on another question, comment on that answer.

Comment: FYI: I never downvoted you.

Comment: @chrisf I see some (6 to be precise) random downvotes one after another, it seems really unusual. Is there anything I could do about it?

Comment: _"f you spot something that looks like serial down-voting that hasn't been picked up then flag one of the posts for us to investigate further."_ -- what would that investigation look like, given that you _"can't see individual votes"_? I am slowly building frustration at the fact that when I try to help by providing feedback, I paint a target on my back. And most revenge downvoters are canny enough to not trigger the only automated script that exists. But as near as I can tell, there aren't any other options for addressing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In [Redirecting to a different url in apache tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23493317), you make a suggestion that you say might work, but that you don't really know for sure, and you don't provide any additional detail.  It is probably more appropriate as a comment.

The other question has an upvoted, accepted answer.  I'd just delete your answer, unless you want to keep the six rep (it has one upvote and two downvotes).

Comment: About the Tomcat -> that is what we have done on our project and it worked. It might be a comment, however I still don't see that as a reason for downvote. About the other question -> there are few important concepts in the answer and the initial downvote was from OP because I had a typo in it (after I've fixed, he did not remove the downvote). But the reason for this question was about suspected random "revenge" downvoting.

Comment: I don't think it's revenge voting.  I think it got downvoted because it's more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Just curious - do you moderators see vote authors?

Comment: No.  We can only see voting patterns in the aggregate.

Comment: @PavelHoral Just to weigh in, I have to agree with _@RobertHarvey_ on this one. I usually downvote answers like that and suggest that they be moved to a comment instead. While it may work, it was an untested solution and is more of a suggestion than an answer. It's a little too speculative, with no context for support.

Comment: I don't think you are getting the point here. These answers are old. They were downvoted in 30s after I made a harsh comment (I know I know...). I thought that moderators can check who downvoted.

Comment: And btw. I will move Tomcat answer to the comment section... but from my point of view it contains answer which can be accepted right away if OP would verifies that it works.

Comment: That still wouldn't make it a good answer.  A good answer contains the solution, in enough detail for the OP or anyone else to implement it, and an explanation of why the solution works.  Part of the problem is that the question isn't really a programming one, and is therefore off-topic, so I closed it.