# Random downvoting for no reason

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

On a question that I answered on Dec 14 '14, I was downvoted yesterday for absolutely no reason.

[What are 'constexpr' useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473795/what-are-constexpr-useful-for/27474062#27474062)

Why is this happening is this a random error or some deliberate attempt to just troll random people? What can people like the moderators do to prevent this or are their hands tied too?

//EDIT

My question - "what do moderators do about random downvotes, and why I was downvoted"

other question -  asks if "there a review process I may ask Stack-overflow to check if the question is rightly down voted or not.

These question can be clearly seen as not duplicates.

There is aslo no answer for the so called "duplicate" answer...

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it was downvoted because substantial portions are copied from an external link. (Admittedly, with attribution.)

Comment: @Radiodef It was my mistake to not add citations in the answer making it seem like I was the author of those points, and I have significantly reformatting and reworded my answer and added citations too. I hope this clears up the issue. If you want to change or suggest anything then feel free to go ahead and edit it.

Comment: I don't think it's not really an issue of *plagiarism*, I mean you had the link posted in the comment below. My guess is it had more to do with amount of effort you had put in to it. (It looks lazy.) Usually if you are summarizing a link you should say something like *"Summarizing from x blog post:"* and put portions you did not write in `>` quote blocks. Of course nobody has stopped by yet to say they are a downvoter and explain why, so maybe they did think that.

Comment: @gnat I respectful disagree that my question is a duplicate of that other question because my question was "what do moderators do about random downvotes, and why I was downvoted", but that other question asks if "there a review process I may ask Stack-overflow to check if the question is rightly down voted or not".

Comment: Who ever decided to close my question because "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." pay close attention that the so called "duplicate" question has no answer.

Comment: answer was down voted because Tim Post lost his keys [yet again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)

Comment: @qnat so my answer was down voted because "people just do odd things" ...  Great answer!

Comment: Ooh, self-referential question !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I was downvoted yesterday for absolutely no reason.

How do you know the downvoter had no reason for the downvote? Something must have made them want to click the downvote button.

> Why is this happening is this a random error or some deliberate attempt to just troll random people?

Random error? Not likely. A troll? Possible, but not very likely given the provided evidence. Votes are supposed to be cast based on the content of the post, not the people who write them.

> What can people like the moderators do to prevent this or are their hands tied too?

Not much, downvotes are anonymous. Moderators don't have access to information on who cast what votes. Only Stack Exchange employees have access to this information. In an extreme case they might investigate, but not for a single downvote.

---

Most-likely someone found the question while searching and found something downvote worthy about the answer. I sympathize with the frustration of not knowing why a post was downvoted. If you think there's something you can improve about your answer, that's really the best thing you could do. Otherwise, it's best to find a way to shrug it off.

Comment: You described the problem the OP is talking about. "How do you know the downvoter had no reason for the downvote?" EXACTLY. There's NO WAY TO KNOW. "Something must have made them want to click the downvote button." Sure, like maybe they just don't like you.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the downvoter had a reason, or maybe not. Maybe someone didn’t like your answer, or they downvoted by accident, or they were just in a bad mood. In any case, you only lost two points of rep, and the downvoter lost one point.

The system tries to detect and reverse [serial voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252087/serial-upvoting-reversed), but there’s nothing the moderators need to do about a few stray votes.

I wouldn’t worry about it. See if there is any way that you can improve your answer, but don’t take downvotes personally.

Also, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255728/random-revenge-downvote-without-a-reason#answer-255729) by a moderator explains things well.

Comment: *"I wouldn’t worry about it. You can make the rep back without too much work."* Or the OP could take this chance to review their answer, ask themselves what problem it might have and try to improve. Downvotes are not for taking reputation away, downvotes indicate there is a problem with the post. I realize you've just intended your statements as encouragement, which is fine, but responding to criticism is important.

Comment: @Radiodef Good point, although the OP doesn’t know what the downvoter didn’t like about his post.

Comment: In which case it would be perfectly fine to come ask on Meta for example, but they came here with the assumption the vote (now *votes*...) was meaningless. That assumption is what my comment was directed towards.